# get first row group by value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm missing one piece of the puzzle. I want to select the first row on `strid` order by `c_date` and group by `strid`.

My sql is:

```
--there should be some 'FIRST' function on strid
select strid over(partition by strid order by c_date) 
from tab
where c_date > :1
  and c_date <= :2
```

tab

```
strid    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
c_date   TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

I can use `row_number` and then select where `row_number=1` but i'm trying to avoid this sub-query, and i'm searching for something more optimized..

Comment: try "first_value(strid) over(partition by strid order by c_date)"

Comment: I don't get it. The "row on strid"? What does that mean? And well, you want the first strid (or row) according to c_date. This gives you *one* strid (or row). So why do you want to group that *one* row by strid???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `first_value`:

```
-- do you really want to partition by strid?
select first_value(strid) over (partition by strid order by c_date) 
  from tab
 where (c_date > :1)
   and (c_date <= :2)
```

Comment: Since it analytic - will it be faster then the `row_number` sql?

Comment: @nir: usually analytic functions are faster; but to be sure you have to inspect the execution plan

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as `select strid from tab where c_date > :1 and c_date <= :2` only obfuscated?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: That's why I've asked about "partition by strid" clause.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: Yes, I thought so :-) I was just confused that nir seems to be happy with the answer got and thought I might have overlooked something.